# Tape capacity and backup routine in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, hp, tape

I have a HP Ultrium 5-scsi tape device on a Linux server and I'm currently using a HP LTO-5 Ultrium RW (model C7975A) tape and I have a couple of questions regarding this setup and does it work.
1 - It seems this tape can reach 3TB for storage considering compression. I'm not using any compression to backup a specific folder. Without compression, how much data this tape can hold? I couldn't find this information anywhere.
2 - I'm trying to do a backup from a folder that has 329GB and it's asking to insert a second tape to continue the backup process. Is this normal? The command I'm using to start this backup is `tar cvMf /dev/nst0 var/Data/backup`
3 - I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on the server.

Can anyone share a light on this? I don't have much knowledge on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. LTO 5 has 1.5TB physical capacity without any compression.
2. Not normal, and looks like there is already some data on
   tape. It is possible to check free space on tape -
   [Determine remaining capacity of LTO tape](https://serverfault.com/questions/853302/determine-remaining-capacity-of-lto-tape)

Comment: Thank you for your help @batistuta09. To mitigate any chances of a tape with some data in it, I opened a brand new tape and tried the same thing. It's keeping asking for a second tape. For testing purposes I inserted a third tape and now it's asking for a fourth tape. I really don't know what's going on here.

Comment: I double checked the amount of data I'm sending to tape and it's ~329GB total.

Comment: try: tar cvf /dev/nst0 var/Data/backup

Comment: "M" in tar is for multi-volume, maybe it is a reason.

Comment: I believe that solved this problem. The process finished without any errors. Thank you very much for your help! I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep to do it.